# Yii2 DynaGrid - how to hide formats from export menu

Tags: yii2, export, yii2-dynagrid

How to hide some formats from export menu in DynaGrid. I was tried settings for GridView widget but doesn't work. Formats are still visible.

```
'exportConfig' => [
    GridView::CSV => ['label' => 'Save as CSV'],
    GridView::HTML => [],
    GridView::PDF => [],
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the above option `exportConfig` under the `gridOptions` and you should specify only those formats that you want to be visible once the dropdown opens, if you want only the `CSV` format then just provide the `CSV` option under the `exportConfig`

```
echo DynaGrid::widget([
    'columns' => $columns,
    'storage' => DynaGrid::TYPE_COOKIE,
    'theme' => 'panel-danger',
    'gridOptions' => [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'exportConfig'=>[
            GridView::CSV=>['label'=>'Save As'],
        ],    
        'panel' => ['heading' => '<h3 class="panel-title">Library</h3>'],

    ],

    'options' => ['id' => 'dynagrid-1'], // a unique identifier is important
]);
```